# Points on lines in lattice plot legend in R

Tags: r, key, legend, lattice

How to draw a legend using lattice where points are shown in the middle of the lines?

There are two great and relevant answers:
[Include lines and points in lattice legend plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23588406/include-lines-and-points-in-lattice-legend-plot-in-r)
and
http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-overlay-lines-and-rectangles-in-lattice-plot-key-td4727682.html

Unfortunately, when I change the **space** parameter to anything else than **right**:

```
auto.key=list(space="right",lines=TRUE,points=TRUE) # worked fine

auto.key=list(space="left",lines=TRUE,points=TRUE) # error message
auto.key=list(x=0, y=0,lines=TRUE,points=TRUE) # error message
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in do.call("fun", legend[[i]]$args, quote = TRUE) : 
  second argument must be a list
```

How can I fix it?

Apologies if the solution is obvious. I am new to R and lattice but have searched for couple of days.
Many thanks for help.

Example:

```
drawComboKey <- function(...) {
    key = simpleKey(...)
    key = draw.key(key, draw = FALSE)

    ngroups <- (length(key$children)-1)/3
    #remove points column
    key$framevp$layout$ncol        <- key$framevp$layout$ncol-3L
    key$framevp$layout$respect.mat <- key$framevp$layout$respect.mat[,-(3:5)]
    key$framevp$layout$widths      <- key$framevp$layout$widths[-(3:5)]

    #adjust background
    key$children[[1]]$col[2]                   <- key$children[[1]]$col[2]-3L
    key$children[[1]]$cellvp$layout.pos.col[2] <- key$children[[1]]$cellvp$layout.pos.col[2]-3L
    key$children[[1]]$cellvp$valid.pos.col[2]  <- key$children[[1]]$cellvp$valid.pos.col[2]-3L

    #combine lines/points
    mylines<-(2+ngroups*2):(1+ngroups*3)
    for(i in mylines) {
        key$children[[i]]$children <- gList(key$children[[i-ngroups]]$children, key$children[[i]]$children)
        key$children[[i]]$childrenOrder         <- names(key$children[[i]]$children)
        key$children[[i]]$col                   <- key$children[[i]]$col-3L
        key$children[[i]]$cellvp$layout.pos.col <- key$children[[i]]$cellvp$layout.pos.col-3L
        key$children[[i]]$cellvp$valid.pos.col  <- key$children[[i]]$cellvp$valid.pos.col-3L
    }

    key$childrenOrder<-names(key$children)
    key
}

library(grid)
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
my.chart <- xyplot(
    Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, 
    iris,
    type = c("p", "l"),
    auto.key = list(space="right", lines=TRUE, points=TRUE) # works fine
    #auto.key = list(space="left", lines=TRUE, points=TRUE) # error message

    #  why is this not working?
    #legend = list(right = list(fun = drawComboKey))
    #  forced below by: my.chart$legend$right$fun = "drawComboKey"
)
my.chart$legend$right$fun = "drawComboKey"
plot(my.chart)
```

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Just including some sample data and something that we can copy/paste into R to get the error would make it much easier to help you. Just a heads up that Lattice isn't the most popular R plotting library now-a-days. If you are new to R, you might want to start with ggplot2. It has many more users and is easier to get help for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there... Be aware that for `space = "left"`, you need to apply your custom function `drawComboKey()` to the legend on the *left*. This analogously applies to `space = "bottom"` (or `"top"`).

```
my.chart = xyplot(Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, 
                  data = iris, type = "b",
                  auto.key = list(space="left", lines = TRUE, points = TRUE))

my.chart$legend$left$fun = "drawComboKey" # same position as 'space' above
plot(my.chart)
```

[image: xyplot(1)]

Note that when working with `x, y` instead of `space`, the function needs to be passed to `my.chart$legend$inside$fun`.